# table_name.* invalid identifier when table_name given an alias

Tags: sql, oracle11g

When I make a SELECT query asking for all the values of a specific table after a series of inner joins, the app complains about me using table_name.* saying it's an "invalid identifier".

```
    SELECT tab_a.*
    FROM tab_a ta INNER JOIN tab_b tb
        ON tab_a.foo = tab_b.foo
    WHERE tab_a.bar LIKE 'a'
    MINUS
    SELECT tab_a.*
    FROM tab_a ta INNER JOIN tab_b tb
        ON tab_a.foo = tab_b.foo
    WHERE tab_b.bar LIKE 'b';
```

This is what I got for all my trouble.

```
    SELECT tab_a.*
                 *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-00904: "TAB_A": invalid identifier
```

I'm using Oracle's server software.

Comment: Huh?  You have  SELECT tab_a after WHERE is not correct.

Comment: @OldProgrammer are you talking about the select statement after
        WHERE tab_b.bar LIKE 'b';
? Because that part of the code was actually part of the error report. I'll edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: Sorry about this, but I just realized that I withheld some information that actually was needed for me to solve my problem. Turns out I have the tables aliases in the FROM clause which caused the problem in the first place, because for some reason Oracle isn't recognizing the original name of the table.

I felt silly for doing this to you guys so I'll just answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I given an alias to the tables in the query. For some reason Oracle would not recognize the original name of the table when an alias was given to it in a query, which is what caused the problem in the first place.

A simple solution to my problem would be to replace all instances of this

```
    tab_a.*
```

with this

```
    ta.*
```

if I were to give an alias to tab_a in, say, the FROM clause.

```
    FROM tab_a ta
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the relevant part of your code:

```
WHERE tab_b.bar LIKE 'b';
    SELECT tab_a.*
```

The semicolon ends your first query.  Your second query is incomplete because it does not have a where clause.  Hence, the error.

Comment: The semicolon was used to indicate the end of the query. The SELECT statement afterwards was actually part of the error message I got, and wasn't something I typed in myself when making the query.